# window.location.url Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm splitting the current url into pieces but I'm doing something wrong with this part to get the current url. How can I solve this?

```
var url = window.location.url;
```

I'm trying to get the current url from the page. This is my function

```
function split(){

    var url = window.location.url;     // This part is not correct
    var firstSplit = url.split('?')[1];

    var name = firstSplit.split('&')[0];
    var age = firstSplit.split('&')[1];

    var parName = name.split('=')[0];
    var nameName = name.split('=')[1];

    var parAge = age.split('=')[0];
    var ageAge = age.split('=')[1];

    document.getElementById("nameId").innerHTML=naamName;
    document.getElementById("ageId").innerHTML=leeftijdAge;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be rather var url = window.location.href?

Comment: If you want to get the query parameters, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+get+query+parameters.

Comment: Also read the [documentation of `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) to learn which properties the object has. `window.location.url` simply does not exist, why do you think it does?

Comment: Felix, that's why I'm asking...

Answer (score 6):

Use `href`:

```
window.location.href
```

For example running it on current SO page gives:

```
console.log(window.location.href);
```

this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10783322/window-location-url-javascript
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the following script to a page; it will display all the properties of the page's url:

```
document.write("<li>location.href = " + location.href);
document.write("<li>location.protocol = " + location.protocol);
document.write("<li>location.host = " + location.host);
document.write("<li>location.hostname= " + location.hostname);
document.write("<li>location.port = " + location.port);
document.write("<li>location.pathname = " + location.pathname);
document.write("<li>location.hash = " + location.hash);
document.write("<li>location.search = " + location.search);
```

better answer found here: https://gist.github.com/jlong/2428561

```
var parser = document.createElement('a');
parser.href = "http://example.com:3000/pathname/?search=test#hash";

parser.protocol; // => "http:"
parser.host;     // => "example.com:3000"
parser.hostname; // => "example.com"
parser.port;     // => "3000"
parser.pathname; // => "/pathname/"
parser.hash;     // => "#hash"
parser.search;   // => "?search=test"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access different parts of the URL directly by using different properties on `window.location`.

The full URL is `window.location.href`, but you seem to be more interested in the query string (the part after the question mark) which you can access with `window.location.search`

A list of other properties is can be found in the [MDN article about `window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location#Properties).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

Or

```
var url = document.URL;
```

and I think Please use function name something different then split because it is a function of PHP and may be reason of problem.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what yo are trying to do after you break the URL into parts but here is how you can get the current URL and put them into variables. You can put them back together however you like latter. Source: [http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/get-url-and-url-parts-in-javascript/][1]

```
var urlNow = window.location.pathname.split('/');

var itNow0 = urlNow[0];
var itNow1 = urlNow[1];
var itNow2 = urlNow[2];
var itNow3 = urlNow[3];

alert(itNow0+ ' ' +itNow1+ ' ' +itNow2+ ' ' +itNow3);
```